# Can I do any action just after return my response with an API GraphQL

Tags: c#, graphql, backend

I am trying to perform an action right after returning my response to a GraphQL API request.
Let me explain: I would like to develop a GraphQL server that receives a certain request from another server and sends a request to this other server just after answering the first request

In comparison, it looks like the OnActionExecuted function with ActionFilterAttribute but I can't implement it for GraphQl, maybe it works only for Rest APIs

I also found the function :
public async override Task AfterExecutionAsync(IExecutionContext context) from class GraphQL.Execution.DocumentExecutionListenerBase but I can't figure out how to implement it so that it triggers after returning my answer

this is the idea but of course it is not what i have tried haha

```
public async Task<sendLinkRequest> sendLinkStatusUpdate(newLinkStatusInput input)
{             
    return _sendLinkRequestService.sendLinkStatusUpdate(input);

    //Doing this after my function return the result
    var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://exemple.com", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
    var sendLinkStatusUpdate = new GraphQLRequest
    {
        Query = "mutation{sendLinkStatusUpdate(input : {newLinkStatus: \"active\"}) {errors {scope message}}}",
        Variables = new
        {
            newLinkStatus = "active"
        }
    };
        
    var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<sendLinkRequest>(sendLinkStatusUpdate);
    
}
```

Anyway, if someone has an idea or a lead I'm interested

Comment: No further code will be run within a C# function after a `return` statement is called. You can, however, call your second asynchronous code without an `await` statement, but then you'd need to set up a handle its completion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment ! I managed to do it like that :)

```
   public sendLinkRequest sendLinkStatusUpdate(newLinkStatusInput input)
    {
        TrackingActionFilter ta = new TrackingActionFilter();
        ta.ProcessCompleted += ta_nextAction; // register with an event
        sendLinkRequest test = ta.StartProcess(input, _sendLinkRequestService);

        return test;

    }

    public async static void ta_nextAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://talentusnewdemo.eu-west-1.beepleapp.eu/b/multi-tenant-api", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
        var sendLinkStatusUpdate = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = "mutation{sendLinkStatusUpdate(input : {newLinkStatus: \"active\"}) {errors {scope message}}}",
            Variables = new
            {
                newLinkStatus = "active"
            }
        };

        var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<sendLinkRequest>(sendLinkStatusUpdate);
        Console.WriteLine("Process Completed!");
    }

 public class TrackingActionFilter
{
    public event EventHandler ProcessCompleted;

    public sendLinkRequest StartProcess(newLinkStatusInput input, IsendLinkRequestService _sendLinkRequestService)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process Started!");
       
        OnProcessCompleted(EventArgs.Empty); //No event data
        return _sendLinkRequestService.sendLinkStatusUpdate(input);
    }

    protected virtual void OnProcessCompleted(EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessCompleted?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```